# Deployment of dotnet core application fails in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created Elastic Beanstalk using Cloudformation template and deploying a dotnet core application in it. While trying to deploy it, the deployment was failing and it shows the below issues:

Inside my environments in Beanstalk im seeing below error:

```
Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

[Instance: i-0d2a1ee08dc2813ff ConfigSet: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild, Hook-PostInit, Hook-PreAppDeploy, Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild, Hook-EnactAppDeploy, Hook-PostAppDeploy, Infra-WriteVersionOnStartup] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: null.
```

The Health status is showing **severe** and if I visit the causes, im getting the below error:

```
Application deployment failed at 2021-08-19T05:36:34Z with exit status 1 and error: .
Process default has been unhealthy for 19 minutes (Target.FailedHealthChecks).
```

In Cloudwatch log groups, the deployment log shows the below deployment failure:

```
AWSBeanstalkCfnDeploy.DeploymentUtils - Unexpected Exception: System.Exception: Exception during deployment. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentDetailedException: Object of type 'package' and path 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' cannot be created. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT. ---> Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: The Zip package 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip' could not be loaded. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip'

INFO 1 AWSBeanstalkCfnDeployApp.DeployApp - Event [ERROR]: Deployment Failed: Unexpected Exception
```

I am using Solution stack as **"64 bit windows server 2019 v2.6.8 running IIS 10.0"**, not sure if that is causing the issue. Can someone provide your inputs on the deployment part on what could could be the issue ? Thanks!

Comment: The error says `Could not find file 'C:\cfn\ebdata\source_bundle_final.zip'`? Is this your file that you create somewhere?

Comment: No Marcin, it was not from our application.

Comment: Hello Marcin, Can you check this if possible ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68889340/build-and-deploy-an-asp-net-core-application-in-aws-codebuild